# Making bash prompt bold

Tags: command-line, bash, customization, bashrc

My `$PS1` variable is

```
\[\033[36m\][\[\033[m\]\[\033[34m\]\u@\h\[\033[m\] \[\033[32m\]\W\[\033[m\]\[\033[36m\]]\[\033[m\] $
```

I wish to maintain the same colors and text but make the prompt appear in **bold**. How do I accomplish this?

I looked over the web and found this can be done using `tput bold`, but the prompt appeared broken to me, I must be doing it wrong.

Answer (score 10):

Bold is set by `01` so you need to add `01;` before each color specification:

```
\[\033[01;36m\][\[\033[m\]\[\033[01;34m\]\u@\h\[\033[m\] \[\033[01;32m\]\W\[\033[m\]\[\033[01;36m\]]\[\033[m\] $
```

Comment: Does not actually explain how to do it.

Comment: @Sqerstet what do you mean? The answer explains you need to add 01; before each color specification to make it bold and includes a modified version of the OP's PS1 with the bold colors correctly applied.

Comment: This is just a string, I don't see any actual command or filename that I'm going to need to solve the problem. You're assuming knowledge that not everyone has! No worries, I filled in the gaps from the other answers.

Comment: Ah, yes OK, I see what you mean @Sqerstet. I guess I just copied directly from the question, and since the OP knew this was the `PS1` variable I thought it was obvious, sorry. You need to run `PS1=\[\033[01;36m\][\[\033[m\]\[\033[01;34m\]\u@\h\[\033[m\] \[\033[01;32m\]\W\[\033[m\]\[\033[01;36m\]]\[\033[m\] $` to change it in the current shell session or, to make it permanent, add that line (`PS1=...`) to your `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 2):

I see there are other answers which are pretty much heuristic. However, if you have more specific needs (as you may do in future), I have a script which may be helpful to you.

```bash
# "Colorize" the plain text.
#
# Usage:
#
#   $ colorize "TEXT" COLOR ["STYLE"] [BACKGROUND]
#
# Notes:
#   - STYLE may be either a single value or a space-delimited string
#
# Examples:
#
#   $ colorize "Hey!" blue bold
#   $ colorize "Yo!" red italic white
#
colorize() {
  text="$1"

  if [ "$color_support" = true ]
  then
    color="$2"
    style=($3)
    background="$4"
    colors=(black red green yellow blue purple cyan white)
    styles=(regular bold italic underline reverse)
    sn=(0 1 3 4 7)

    for n in {0..7}
    do
      [[ $color == ${colors[n]} ]] && color="3$n"
      [[ $background == ${colors[n]} ]] && background="4$n"
      for s in ${!style[@]}
      do
        [[ ${style[s]} == ${styles[n]} ]] && style[s]="${sn[n]}"
      done
    done

    ! [ -z $style ] && style="${style[*]};" && style=${style// /;}
    ! [ -z $background ] && background=";$background"
    background+="m"

    text="\e[$style$color$background$text\e[0m"
  fi

  echo "$text"
}
```

It offers bold, italic, underline and reverse text styles, aswell as the supported colors in bash. You can also export the function in case you don't want to add it to `.bash_profile` directly.

Here is an example how you could use it for formatting the prompt (note the prompt requires a bit different syntax):

```
colorize_prompt() {
  colorize $@ &>/dev/null

  if [ "$color_support" = true ]
  then
    text="\[\e[$style$color$background\]$1\[\e[0m\]"
  fi

  echo $text
}

# Main prompt
PS1="$(colorize_prompt "火" purple bold) $(colorize_prompt "\w" blue bold) "

# Continuation prompt
PS2="$(colorize_prompt "|" cyan bold) "
```

The script is an [exempt](https://github.com/zdroid/dotfiles/blob/master/bash/bash_functions) from my [dotfiles](https://github.com/zdroid/dotfiles).

Comment: Cool function. It should be noted that you need to have somewhere the variable color_support sets as true, `export color_support=true`. It does not exist on my system. I had to add a `-e` in the last `echo`, `echo -e $text`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

You try something like this:

```
PS1="\[\033[36m\][\[\033[m\]\[\033[34m\]\[\e[1m \u@\h \e[0m\] \[\033[32m\]\W\[\033[m\]\[\033[36m\]]\[\033[m\] $"
```

For permanent change to bash prompt put it in `.bashrc`

**Solution 2:** Using `tput`

```
reset=$(tput sgr0)
bold=$(tput bold)
black=$(tput setaf 0)
red=$(tput setaf 1)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
blue=$(tput setaf 4)
magenta=$(tput setaf 5)
cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
white=$(tput setaf 7)
user_color=$blue
PS1="\[$reset\]\[$cyan\][ \[$bold\]\[$user_color\]\u@\h\
\[$reset\]\[$blue\]\W\[$cyan\] ] \[$reset\]\[$reset\]\\$\[$reset\] "
```

Comment: sorry but that did nothing

Comment: Please check this now it was wrong paste before.

Comment: works but i lost all color

Comment: This works perfectly fine in my 2 instance of Ubuntu 14.04.3 version. You might have some issue with character encoding.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using ubuntu 18.04, run the following commands

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.profile
```

That's it. You'll have a bold **user@host** at the prompt

Comment: This is not what the question asked for (he wanted to keep the colors he set). Moreover, if the user already uses a ~/.profile file, he will lose evrything he put inside.